# Acquiring pixel data from TIFF-file into CSV-file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, export, csv, pixel

I have a TIFF-file which gives me a value of forest age per pixel in the whole Amazon basin.
I am trying to do a spatial-statistical analysis between forest age and climatic variables.
For this my goal is to have an attribute table that shows the forest age, climate variable, lat/long per pixel.

This TIFF file did not come with a text file or CSV, and I am not able to extract an adequate attribute table.

How can I acquire a CSV file with all the pixels values in QGIS for my study area? (age of forest, lat/lon, etc.)

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Why do you need a csv file? I suspect there will be an easier way to do what ever you are trying to do with out it

Comment: @IanTurton I have updated my description showing what I want to do. I hope this is clear now, any suggestions are welcome :)